# If a process is 0 up to a stopping time, then the ito integral up to the stopping time is 0.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

[image]

The proof for this theorem is quite long and Im reading it. But why is this not immediate? If the function is 0 up to the stopping time and we integrate it up to the stopping time, the integral should be 0.

Does that argument not work because the integral is integrating with respect to every possible brownian and not a single trajectory. Therefore, it's aggregating over all the possible stopping times when calculating f(w,s). So the stopping time up to a single stopping time might be something non-zero?

Comment: Yes, it is not immediate because the Itô integral is not defined as an pathwise integral.

Comment: One the other hand, it is almost immediate, because for an integrand of the type you have, the integral is an $L^2$ limit of Riemann sums, each of which vanishes (before time $\nu$) because the integrand vanishes there.